# SQL Union Count to Sum Data

Tags: sql-server, count, sum, aggregate, union

I have a bit of a complex query .... I need to do an update statement on the summation of two union-ed SQL queries (problem is the data in the queries isn't numeric so i'm counting rows instead of summing values) but I then need to sum those rows.

```
UPDATE  #LT_Actuals_TEMP 
SET     pCount =  h.countPerfs
FROM    (
select count(distinct c.perf_description) as countPerfs, b.program, b.Prog_id
from #LT_Actuals_TEMP TableP
where       a.Performances = 'Y' and a.current_inactive = 0
group by    b.Program, b.Prog_id
union 
select  distinct count(p.perf_code) as countPerfs, x.value, b.Prog_id
from    T_PERF p    
where   x.content_type = 23
group by  x.value, b.Prog_id
) h where h.Prog_id = #LT_Actuals_TEMP.program_id
```

the first query data comes back as such

```
countPerfs   program    Prog_id
7            Name       31
```

and second query comes back as

```
countPerfs   program    Prog_id
1            Name       31
```

what I need `pCount`  to be set to at the end of the day is 8

Expected results
when I do `select * from #LT_Actuals_TEMP` 
I see the value
8 for the Program Name, Id 31

Comment: please post your expected result

Comment: Also you took out a bunch of `... \` of within the code but that was to show a large complex query its not that simple as it is above. But as long as its clear what is happening I'm good with it.

Comment: please check this link to improve your question,it seems like you are trying to update count of those both,but not sure:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @TheGameiswar no I thought I explained my issue - I have two unioned query where I can only do counts each of those queries returns a value I need to sum those values and in my update statement set the pCount field to the sum of those two internal values. (but I can't use sum because all the data is not mathematical so I'm counting distinct rows). does that help?

Comment: As posted this query is just gibberish. Aliases that don't exist and all sort of issues. I am hoping this is because you removed a lot of code to post. Also, it is not a good habit to use a,b,c as aliases. Give your aliases a chance at clarity. You will appreciate better aliases in the long run when you have to maintain your code. One last thing, do you really need UNION here or should this be UNION ALL? UNION will typically be slower because it removes duplicates.

Comment: there are at least 5 lines of joins and where statements for each I removed there fore I wasnt expecting an exact copy and paste of my internal queries for the solution. I was hoping a suggestion/guide in the right direction about how to take my set up and adjust it so I can sum the value returned in my unioned selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by adding another level in the from part where you sum up the data returned from the union.

Your query seems to be missing some source tables (as there are aliases used that don't point to anything) so I guess you're removed some parts, but in general it should look something like this:

```
UPDATE  #LT_Actuals_TEMP 
SET     pCount =  h.sum_of_countperfs    
FROM    (
  select program, prog_id, sum(countPerfs) as sum_of_countperfs
  from (
    select count(distinct c.perf_description) as countPerfs, b.program, b.Prog_id
    from #LT_Actuals_TEMP TableP
    where       a.Performances = 'Y' and a.current_inactive = 0
    group by    b.Program, b.Prog_id
    union all
    select  distinct count(p.perf_code) as countPerfs, x.value, b.Prog_id
    from    T_PERF p    
    where   x.content_type = 23
    group by  x.value, b.Prog_id
  ) as sub_q group by program, prog_id
) h where h.Prog_id = #LT_Actuals_TEMP.program_id
```

Also, you probably want to use `union all` so that duplicates are not removed.

Comment: Im very sorry for the confusion but I'm having a hard time understanding what was added here to solve the problem.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR I tried to format it better so that it might be easier to see the addition. I wrapped your original union query in an outer query that sums the data.

Comment: Ahh I get the concept, you added one extra level. You summed/aggregated my data in a select one level up and then did the update

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Exactly.